# bash script doesn't act like shell

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion, extglob

Here is my script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

x="aabcaa"
y=${x##*(a)}
echo $y
```

It outputs `aabcaa` when I expect `bcaa`.

When I try the same commands on a bash shell (got with `bash` command from zsh shell), everything works as I want. I checked the version with `bash --version` and `/bin/bash --version`. Obviously, the two commands output the same thing. The unexpected behavior of the script is the same in a zsh shell and in a bash shell.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You probably have the `extglob` option (enabling extended glob pattern syntax) set in your interactive shell (set in ~/.bash_profile or somewhere like that). If you want to use extended glob syntax in a script, you need to add `shopt -s extglob` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Run this: `shopt -p >inter; bash -c 'shopt -p >noninter'; diff --suppress-common-lines -y inter noninter` or this: `{ shopt -p; bash -c 'shopt -p';} | sort -k3 | uniq -u`

Comment: Sorry Gorgon, I thought I had thanked you and I hadn't. You solved my problem (without any delay !).